# Class cluster with clang: how to use `__attribute__((objc_method_family(none)))`?

Tags: xcode, warnings, automatic-ref-counting, clang, class-cluster

I want to implement a class cluster (with ARC), but clang gets in the way. Here is one init method that returns a concrete instance of another class - which is the point of class clusters:

```
@implementation PlaceholderServer
- (Server *) init {
    MockServer *concreteServer = [[MockServer alloc] init];
    return concreteServer;
}
@end
```

And clang complains on the `return` statement:

```
warning: incompatible pointer types returning 'MockServer *__strong' from a function with result type 'PlaceholderServer *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

I understand the reason for that warning: `init` is recognized by clang as belonging to the `init` family of methods which are supposed to return instances of the implementing class (or perhaps a subclass). That's typically not the case in a class cluster where the actual concrete class to instantiate can vary depending on whatever condition.

clang provides an annotation to override the automatic recognition of method families: `__attribute__((objc_method_family(FAMILLY)))`, where familly can be one of `alloc`, `copy`, `init`, `mutableCopy`, or `new`. It can also be `none`, about which the documentation says: "If family is `none`, the method has no family, even if it would otherwise be considered to have one based on its selector and type."

Unfortunately, I can't manage to make it work in my case. If I add the following declaration to the `@interface`:

```
- (SGIServer *) init __attribute__((objc_method_family(none)));
```

Then the warning doesn't go away. If I add the attribute to the implementation:

```
- (Server *) init __attribute__((objc_method_family(none)))
{
    MockServer *concreteServer = [[MockServer alloc] init];
    return concreteServer;
}
```

Then the warning doesn't go away *and* I also get an error:

```
error: method was declared as an 'init' method, but its implementation doesn't match because its result type is unrelated to its receiver type
- (SGIServer *) init __attribute__((objc_method_family(none)))
^
```

And if I do both, the initial warning doesn't go away, but I get an *additional* warning:

```
warning: attributes on method implementation and its declaration must match [-Wmismatched-method-attributes]
```

So I suppose I am missing something elementary, but what?

This is with Xcode 4.3.2 or Xcode 4.4DP2.

Answer (score 0):

No messing with attributes should be necessary; you should be able to instead `return (id) concreteServer;`, which switches to dynamic typing.